# How to use completablefuture and Streams together

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-8, java-stream, completable-future

I want to work with `CompletableFuture` and `Stream` at the same time. Something like transforming a `CompletableFuture<Stream<String>>` into a `CompletableFuture<Stream<Team>>`.

I have done something similar from `CompletableFuture<String>` to `CompletableFuture<Integer>`.

```
CompletableFuture<Stream<String>> getMostPopularTeamNames(int maxResults) {
    CompletableFuture<Stream<String>> mostPopularTeamNames;

    WorldCupSocialApi.getMostPopularTeamNames(1, maxResults, teams -> {
        mostPopularTeamNames = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> teams.stream());
    });

    return mostPopularTeamNames;
}
```

I am trying to do something like:

```
CompletableFuture<Stream<Team>> cf = getMostPopularTeamNames(5).thenApply(s -> {
    s.map(name -> new Team(name))
}
```

But I am not sure if I the `s` is going to be the `String` or the `Stream`, and if I can map it that way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, let's dissect the problem into two smaller problems:

1. Converting a `CompletableFuture<T>` to `CompletableFuture<R>`
2. Converting a `Stream<String>` into `Stream<Team>`

The first one can be achieved using `thenApply` or `thenApplyAsync`.
The second one can be achieved using a standard `map` operation on a `Stream` instance.

And now once you try to combine them, think about just like about applying any other transformation of `CompletableFuture<String>`, and now it should become clear that you can simply do:

```
CompletableFuture<Stream<Team>> cf = getMostPopularTeamNames(5)
  .thenApply(s -> s.map(name -> new Team(name));
```

`s` is a `Stream<String>` that gets converted into `Stream<Team>` - there's no magical conversion between these two types

Comment: But there’s not much sense in such a design, as Streams are lazy and do not perform any work before chaining the terminal operation, so this code is unnecessarily doing trivial operations asynchronously.

Comment: @Holger agreed, treated it as syntax riddle